# Find the element that appears once

Tags: algorithm

Find the element that appears once

Given an array where every element occurs three times, except one element which occurs only once. Find the element that occurs once.

Expected time complexity is O(n) and O(1) extra space.

Examples:

Input: arr[] = {12, 1, 12, 3, 12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}

Output: 2

Comment: Hint: sum them...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If O(1) space constraint was not there, you could've gone for a hashmap with values being the count of occurrences.

```
int getUniqueElement(int[] arr)
{
    int ones = 0 ; //At any point of time, this variable holds XOR of all the elements which have appeared "only" once.
    int twos = 0 ; //At any point of time, this variable holds XOR of all the elements which have appeared "only" twice.
    int not_threes ;

    for( int x : arr )
    {
        twos |= ones & x ; //add it to twos if it exists in ones
        ones ^= x ; //if it exists in ones, remove it, otherwise, add it

        // Next 3 lines of code just converts the common 1's between "ones" and "twos" to zero.

        not_threes = ~(ones & twos) ;//if x is in ones and twos, dont add it to Threes.
        ones &= not_threes ;//remove x from ones
        twos &= not_threes ;//remove x from twos
    } 
    return ones;
}
```

Basically, it makes use of the fact that `x^x = 0` and `0^x=x`. So all paired elements get XOR'd and vanish leaving the lonely element.

In short :

If a bit is already in ones, add it to twos.

XOR will add this bit to ones if it's not there or remove this bit from ones if it's already there.

If a bit is in both ones and twos, remove it from ones and twos.

When finished, ones contains the bits that only appeared 3*n+1 times, which are the bits for the element that only appeared once.

Comment: This is not giving correct output, try it with {1,3,1}

Comment: I think doing a NOR for all elements in the array would work. NOR of an element with itself thrice gives 0. NOR of zero with the individual element will just flip the bits so doing another negation on top would give the element occurring once. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @AnkitZalani, your example is invalid. One element should occur once, and the others should occur exactly 3 times.

Comment: @user2103008 The problem with the NOR idea is that NOR is *not* associative.  So the result of "doing a NOR for all elements" depends on the order in which they were combined.  Example: 0 nor (0 nor 1) = 0 nor 0 = 1, but (0 nor 0) nor 1 = 1 nor 1 = 0.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript solution:

```
function findElement(arr) {
  var ones = 0;
  var twos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ones = (ones ^ arr[i]) & ~twos;
    twos = (twos ^ arr[i]) & ~ones;
  }
  return ones;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm), Median of elements of an array can be found in worst-case O(n) time and O(1) extra-space. So we can solve the problem with divide-and-conquer method:

Find the median in O(n) time and count number of elements which are less than or equal to median in O(n). If this number is 3k+1, it means that answer is less than or equal to median, so omit the elements which are greater than median in O(n). Else, omit ones which are less than or equal to median. Then recursively find answer in remaining elements in T(n/2). Note: number of remaining elements is n/2 because we have omitted half of elements.

So T(n) = T(n/2)+O(n) = O(n) and we need O(1) extra space.

Comment: Could you show that it works using the above example? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
// as we know every number is present thrice except one number means   that if we observe the bits at each place we will find that the set bits at each place are either multiple of 3n or 3n+1 ( when unique num has set bit at that place )
```

ex -  12, 1, 12, 3, 12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3

```
12- 1 1 0 0
1 - 0 0 0 1
12- 1 1 0 0
3 - 0 0 1 1
12- 1 1 0 0
1 - 0 0 0 1
1 - 0 0 0 1
2 - 0 0 1 0
3 - 0 0 1 1
3 - 0 0 1 1
```

---

```
    3 3 4 6    ( 3n or 3n+1 ) form
```

where it is of 3n+1 form means unique number has set bit here so now we  extract the unique num easily as we know its set bit position.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   
   int n,num,j;
   int set[64]={0}; // maximum bits
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>num;
       j=0;

       while(num){
           set[j]+=(num&1);
           num=num>>1;
           j++;
       }
   }
int ans=0,p=1;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    ans+=(set[i]%3)*p;
    p=p*2;
}
cout<<ans<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution similar to the one proposed by mhsekhavat. Instead of determining the median, I propose using the partition algorithm of the Dutch national flag problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem (yes, I am dutch and was educated in Dijkstra's style).

The result of applying the algorithm is an array partitioned in a red, white and blue part. The white part can be considered the pivot. Note that the white part consists of all elements equal to the pivot, so the white part will exist of 1 or 3 elements.
The red part consists of elements smaller than the pivot and the blue part consists of elements larger than the pivot. (Note that the red and blue parts are not sorted!)

Next, count the number of elements of the red, white and blue parts. If any part consists of 1 element, then that is the number you are looking for. Otherwise, either the red or the blue part consists of 3k+1 elements, for a given number of k. Repeat the algorithm on the part that consists of 3k+1 elements. Eventually one of the parts will have size 1.

The algorithm runs in O(n) and needs O(1) variables.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is already answered, I found the following more intuitive and hence adding it as an answer. Originally from [here](https://www.quora.com/Given-an-integer-array-such-that-every-element-occurs-3-times-except-one-element-which-occurs-only-once-how-do-I-find-that-single-element-in-O-1-space-and-O-n-time-complexity)

```
int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
    /*Bits in 'ones' are set to 1, when that particular bit 
      occurs for the first time. Bits in 'twos' are set to 1, 
      when that particular bit occurs for the second time. If a 
      bit is occurring for more than 2 times, we throw it away 
      and start counting again.*/
    int ones = 0;
    int twos = 0;
    for (auto elem : nums) {
        int onesOld = ones;
        /* (ones ^ elem): consider the ith bit in 'ones' be 0 (i.e. ith 
           bit has not occurred till now or has occurred 2 times) and in 
           'elem' be 1. So, for the ith bit (ones ^ elem) gives 1. Now,
           ith bit could have occurred even number of times as well (i.e. 
           ith bit in twos is set to 1). If that was the case, we 
           would like to ignore such bit. This last part is taken care 
           of by '&' with '~twos' 
           */
        ones = (ones ^ elem) & ~twos;
        /* (onesOld & elem) gives the bits which have occurred ones 
           and also occur in this particular element. (twos & ~elem) 
           gives the bits that have occurred twice and do not occur 
           in this element. Both these cases take care of the bits 
           that have occurred 2 times (although a bit might be set 
           more than 2 times, like 5,7... but we take only modulo 3 
           count).
        */
        twos = (onesOld & elem) | (twos & ~elem);
    }
    return ones;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider their binary representation and sum the number of bits at each location. For example [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] gives [4, 4], considering just the two bits needed to represent these numbers. Taking mod 3 of this gives [1,1] which is 11 = 3 in binary which is the correct answer. This is still O(1) space because it doesn't scale with the number of elements, but could still have a huge pre-factor.

Some sloppy cpp code:

```
int l = arr.size();
int nbits = 32;
vector<int> bits(nbits,0);

for( int i = 0; i < l; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < nbits; j++ ){
        bits[j] +=  ( A[i] >>j ) & 1;
    }
}
int missing = 0;
for( int j = 0 ; j < nbits; j++ ){
    if( bits[j]%3 == 1 ){
         set_bit( missing, j );
    }
}
```

Almost certainly this can be optimized by folk who know more about bitwise operations than I do (nobody likes loops within loops...). Anyway, I think this should work with any 'k-duplicates except for one of them' type problems, assuming the missing one only appears once.

EDIT: Appears this answer is also detailed here by Leo Polovets
https://www.quora.com/Given-an-integer-array-such-that-every-element-occurs-3-times-except-one-element-which-occurs-only-once-how-do-I-find-that-single-element-in-O-1-space-and-O-n-time-complexity

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use XOR. XOR of all array elements gives us the number with a single occurrence. The idea is based on the following two facts.
a) XOR of a number with itself is 0.
b) XOR of a number with 0 is number itself.

```
int findSingle(int ar[], int ar_size) 
    { 
        // Do XOR of all elements and return 
        int res = ar[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < ar_size; i++) 
            res = res ^ ar[i]; 

        return res; 
    }
```

Comment: XORing an element that appears three times will give back that element, same as if it appears once: 12^12^12=12. So this doesn't differentiate between elements appearing one, or thrice, because XORing will return all elements with odd occurences!

Comment: Please read the question properly. Your proposed solution works for the case where all elements but one exists TWICE and NOT THRICE

Answer (score -2):

Add each number once and multiply the sum by 3, we will get thrice the sum of each element of the array. Store it as thrice_sum. Subtract the sum of the whole array from the thrice_sum and divide the result by 2. The number we get is the required number (which appears once in the array).

```
def singlenumbers(arr):
   return (3* sum(set(arr)) - sum(arr))//2
arr =  [6, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6]
print(singlenumbers(arr))
```

Comment: Since you use a set, it won't have O(1) space as expected in the original question.

Answer (score -3):

```
def apperasonce(arr1):
    n=len(arr1)
    for i in range(0,n):
        if arr1.count(arr1[i]) == 1:
            return arr1[i]

arr1=[12,1,12,3,12,1,1,2,3,3]
a=apperasonce(arr1)
print(a)
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), not O(n). `count` has a loop over all `n` inside it.